Understanding the basics of involute curves
I've had no need to get into the subject of involute curves until now, when curiosity led me there. Now, I need some confirmation/correction of what I believe I understand.
As I've read it many places, an involute is generated by attaching a string to a curve and keeping it taut while winding the string against the curve. The locus of points generated by the end of the string then is the curve's involute.
That suggests two things to me, and I'm looking for confirmation/correction as appropriate:

The length of the string has to be specified going in. Correct?
Given that the length of the string is arbitrary, there are an infinite number of involutes of any given curve. Also correct?

Thanks very much.

The string is wrapped around the curve (like scotch tape in a dispenser) and you unwrap it, keeping it taught. The string is typically of arbitrary (perhaps infinite) length and the string is of zero thickness. To answer your ambiguity question, the issue is at what point you start unwrapping the string.

Thanks to both for confirming what I'd thought. M. Daoust addressed the second of my questions explicitly. Mr. Shifrin addressed the first as well, and he implicitly mentioned something I didn't: namely, there are an infinite number of starting points as well, which also leads to an infinite number of involute curves. This is what happens when a retired engineer starts thinking about the analytic geometry courses he had years ago...
